# Displaying all posts with custom taxonomy using WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

[image]

I am trying to display a custom post type that has a custom taxonomy, but I am not having any luck. Nothing is showing up. I appreciate any help.

Post type = university

Custom Taxonomy slug = country

I wanted to show all the country list using WP_Query as there are some custom fields in this taxonomy. Also, on click of any country, it should redirect to a country page with its details

Below is my code

```
<?php
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'university',
        'tax_query' => array(
             array(
                 'taxonomy' => 'country'
             )
         )
      );

     $query = new WP_Query($args);

     if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
           $query->the_post();
     ?>

              <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 

                 <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

              </a>
     <?php
        }
     }
     wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have modified your code, Please try it.

```
<?php

      $custom_terms = get_terms('country');
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'university',
        'tax_query' => array(             
             array(
                'taxonomy' => 'country',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_terms[0]->slug, // or the category name e.g. Germany
            ),
         )
      );

     $query = new WP_Query($args);

     if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
           $query->the_post();
     ?>

              <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 

                 <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

              </a>
     <?php
        }
     }
     wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

We get all the terms of a taxonomy, loop through them, and fire off a title link to each post that belongs to that term.